# React-Select on selecting a value the dropdown options unavailable

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Process the prop from another component to match in the react-select options

```
const labelOptionsProcessed = []
    labelOptions.map(item => {
        let tmpObj = {
            id: item.id,
            label: item.name,
            name: item.name
        }
        labelOptionsProcessed.push(tmpObj)
    })
```

tmpObj is the structure of the options

```
<Select
      options={labelOptionsProcessed}
       isMulti
 ></Select>
```

When a select a dropdown value , the options change to no data available

Before selecting an Option :

[image]

After Selecting an Option:

[image]

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4ddnq7

Comment: could you please create a https://stackblitz.com/edit/react

Comment: Sure @Kalhan.Toress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set a `value` property for options instead of `id`

EX:

```
const labelOptionsProcessed = []
labelOptions.map(item => {
    let tmpObj = {
        value: item.id, // here
        label: item.name,
        name: item.name
    }
    labelOptionsProcessed.push(tmpObj)
});
```

I guess this is not the proper way to generate the options list, I'd do something like this

```
const labelOptionsProcessed = labelOptions.map(({ value, name: label, name }) => {
  return {
    value,
    label,
    name
  };
});
```

Comment: This talks about the code quality, Not why the list disappears, when selected,But still thanks , I actually used the answer you mentioned, But refactored it so people who read the question can understand clearly what's going, Hence the descriptive code which increases readability

Comment: you haven't read the whole post, just read the first section and you will see why it's getting empty :) thanks

Comment: in short, remove the `id` property from the options and add `value` property instead of `id`

Comment: If you are still struggling here is the demo of the fix I have mentioned https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tvm5ct

Comment: Oh my bad sorry, This helped, worked fine